# How to solve undefined reference to `iargc_' error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to execute a program named "gribextract" by executing "make" command.

I am getting an error as

---

```
gfortran -o hrldas_extract_point -fconvert=big-endian -g  -I. \
        hrldas_extract_point.o arguments_module.o module_date_utilities.o 
llxy_generic.o lccone.o \
        -L/home/Admin/Workstation/NETCDF413/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf

arguments_module.o: In function `initialize':
/home/Admin/Workstation/Hrldas/Utility_programs/arguments_module.f90:400: undefined reference to `iargc_'   
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hrldas_extract_point] Error 1
```

---

How to solve this error. Below are my user build option

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

COMPILERF90     =   gfortran
FREESOURCE      =   -ffree-form  -ffree-line-length-none -cpp
F90FLAGS        =   -fconvert=big-endian -g 
MODFLAG         =   -I
LDFLAGS         =
CPP             =   cpp
CPPFLAGS        =   -C -P -traditional -D_GFORTRAN_ # -D_HRLDAS_URBAN_
LIBS            =   
LIBJASPER       =   -ljpeg -L/home/Admin/Workstation/Hrldas/Jasper/lib -ljasper
INCJASPER       =   -I/home/Admin/Workstation/Hrldas/Jasper/include
NETCDFMOD       =   -I/home/Admin/Workstation/NETCDF413/include
NETCDFLIB       =   -L/home/Admin/Workstation/NETCDF413/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
HDF5LIB         =   -L/home/Admin/Workstation/HDF5-Ver-1.8.14/lib -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lm -lcurl
NETCDF4_COMPRESS=       YES
BZIP2           =   YES
BZIP2_LIB       =   -lbz2
BZIP2_INCLUDE   =   -I/usr/include
RM              =   rm -f
CC             =    cc

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: I *think* the issue is that `/HRLDAS_COLLECT_DATA/lib/arguments_module.F` declares `iargc` as `external` but no external definition is provided. Since `gfortran` provides an [intrinsic iargc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IARGC.html) for backward compatibility, you might want to try removing the `external` keyword there (or changing it to `intrinsic`).

Comment: Sorry but how to do that

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW here is how I was able to build `gribextract` from the `hrldas-v3.4.1` tarball, on Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64. **DISCLAIMER: I am NOT a Fortran programmer, in fact I usually only find myself wrangling with it in these kinds of 'legacy' applications**.

1. Modify the `user_build_options` to remove the `-C` option to `cpp`, and also to set appropriate include and lib paths for `jasper` and `netcdf` (in my case, the standard locations). *Note: removal of the `-C` may only be necessary if you're using gfortran > 4.8.x*.

   ```
   COMPILERF90         =   gfortran
   FREESOURCE          =   -ffree-form  -ffree-line-length-none
   F90FLAGS            =   -fconvert=big-endian # -g
   MODFLAG             =   -I
   LDFLAGS             =
   CPP                 =   cpp
   CPPFLAGS            =   -P -traditional -D_GFORTRAN_ # -D_HRLDAS_URBAN_
   LIBS                =
   LIBJASPER           =   -ljpeg -ljasper
   INCJASPER           =   -I/usr/include
   NETCDFMOD           =   -I/usr/include
   NETCDFLIB           =   -L/usr/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
   HDF5LIB             =   -L/usr/lib -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lm -lcurl
   NETCDF4_COMPRESS    =       YES
   BZIP2               =   YES
   BZIP2_LIB           =   -lbz2
   BZIP2_INCLUDE       =   -I/usr/include
   RM                  =   rm -f
   CC                  =   cc
   ```
2. Convert all the `external` declarations of `iargc` to `intrinsic`

   ```
   find . -name '*.F' -execdir sed -i 's/external :: iargc/intrinsic :: iargc/' {} \;
   ```

   (The `intrinsic` keyword may be superfluous - I didn't try just removing `external`.)
3. Edit `Utility_programs/modify_wrfinput.F` to work around an error concerning the passing of loop variable `i` to the `nf90_def_dim` function as an `intent(out)` parameter: the `diff` being

   ```
   /hrldas-v3.4.1$ diff Utility_programs/modify_wrfinput.F{.bak,}
   387c387
   <   integer :: iret, i, j
   ---
   >   integer :: iret, i, j, iout
   410c410,411
   <      iret = nf90_def_dim (copy_ncid, trim(name), lendd, i)
   ---
   >      iout = i
   >      iret = nf90_def_dim (copy_ncid, trim(name), lendd, iout)
   ```
4. Build the top level software

   ```
   /hrldas-v3.4.1$ make
   ```
5. Build the `Utility_programs` software

   ```
   /hrldas-v3.4.1$ cd Utility_programs
   /hrldas-v3.4.1/Utility_programs$ make
   ```
6. Test the executable

   ```
   hrldas-v3.4.1/Utility_programs$ ./gribextract -h

   **************************************************************************

   ./gribextract
              -- extracts specified fields from a GRIB (Edition 1 or Edition 2) file.
   <snip>
   ```

Comment: Changing the definition of IARGC from "external" to "intrinsic" worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to link your program with `gfortran` library. Add `-lgfortran` to your link parameters.

**UPD**: it seems that `iargc` is handled in a different way depending on how exactly it is used in program and on program compilation options. Here are two useful links: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2007-01/msg00236.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20248

Some summary:

- You should not include `extern iargc` in your code
- You should not use `-std=f95` (though you do not seem to use it)

Maybe you need to play around a bit with possible options, I have not tried them.

Comment: Petr I am new to this, could you please tell me exactly where to add -lgfortran, what this link parameter is ?

Comment: @dSb, I do not know your build system (where the build options come from), so I can not tell where this option really belongs to. As a quick fix, you can try adding it to `F90FLAGS` line: `F90FLAGS        =   -fconvert=big-endian -g -lgfortran`. You can verify that it works by checking the output like the one you quoted in question and checking the `-lgfortran` finds its way there.

Comment: @dSb, can you post the updated compiler/linker output?

Comment: You did not get `-lgfortran` printed among the lines before the error message, in the line with `gfortran -o ...`?

Comment: Yeah, Petr it changed to 
gfortran -o hrldas_extract_point -fconvert=big-endian -lgfortran  -I. \
  hrldas_extract_point.o arguments_module.o module_date_utilities.o llxy_generic.o lccone.o \
  -L/home/dsbisht/Workstation/NETCDF413/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
arguments_module.o: In function `__arguments_module_MOD_initialize':
arguments_module.f90:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `iargc_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hrldas_extract_point] Error 1

Comment: @dSb Oh, I found some more links that might be useful: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2007-01/msg00236.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20248